# How do I re-enable Firefox's "mixed ssl with non-ssl elements in page" warning?

Tags: firefox

I accidentally pressed Enter when this warning first showed up on my freshly-installed system before having a chance to read it.

Now I'd like to have the warning back because I feel insecure. It's probably some setting in about:config, but I can't find it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `about:config`, set the `security.warn_viewing_mixed` setting to True.